# Array of IDs in column referencing different table's row

Tags: sql, postgresql

Say I have a table containing different categories.. then another table where a column must reference array of multiple categories within the first.

What is this called and what is the best way to do this?

Postgres Dialect :)

```
Category Id | Category Name
1           | Category 1
2           | Category 2

Product Id | Product Name | Categories
1          | Product 1    | 1,2
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is called just integer array, `int[]` (or `int8[]` if you need 8-byte integers).

```
create table category (
  id serial primary key,
  name text not null
);

create table product (
  id bigserial primary key,
  name test not null,
  category_ids int[] not null
);
```

You can use this approach and even add GIN index over `product.category_ids` to speed up lookups like `select * from product where '{2}'::int[] <@ category_ids;` -- but the obvious drawback here is that Postgres will not be able to ensure referential integrity -- you cannot define a foreign key for `int[]`.

Alternatively, you could use `jsonb` data type instead of `int[]` and also add GIN index on that column to speed up searches.

If you want to have FKs (which is very good and right desire), just follow the traditional approach, EAV:

```
create table category (
  id serial primary key,
  name text not null
);

create table product (
  id bigserial primary key,
  name test not null
);

create table product2category (
  product_id int8 not null references product(id),
  category_id int not null references category(id),
  primary key (product_id, category_id)
);
```

There is a number of articles discovering pros and cons of EAV vs. `int[]` (aka "intarray") or `jsonb` approaches, here is one of them: http://coussej.github.io/2016/01/14/Replacing-EAV-with-JSONB-in-PostgreSQL/ -- I recommend to google that topic and learn, it will help to decide what is better for your case.